# Starting for Loop from second element - Shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to start iterating over the array from the second element for the below array in shell script.

```
number=${number:-(12 20 43 45 67 40)}
```

Could you please help me on how to use the For Loop to iterate starting from the second element (ie 20 in this case)

```
for i in ${number[@]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which one it's Powershell (or) Linux Bash shell? You have tagged both.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `${number[@]:1}` to start iterating from 2nd element:

```
for i in "${number[@]:1}"; do
    echo "Processing: $i"
done
```

Comment: Actually `:1` is not 2nd element, it just a part of 12 from `$number` without first 1: `2 20 43 45 67 40)`

Comment: `:1` gives array elements starting from 2nd position. Test with: `number=(20 43 45 67 40); echo "${number[@]:1}"`

Answer (score -1):

I usually split the array into $firstLine and $restOfLines like this:

```
$firstLine, $restOfLines = $sourceArray
foreach($line in $restOfLines) { ... }
```

See this article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-tip-how-to-shift-arrays/